# Make Joomla 3.x routing prioritize redirects above article ids?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, joomla

So I am upgrading an existing website(different CMS) to the Joomla 3.4.1 CMS, and I'm running into the following problem.

Because it's a replacement for an old website, I need to make 301 redirects to make sure no links appear broken. 
The old website used url's like '/10/Terms_of_use.html', basically url's which start with numbers. This results in the situation where Joomla looks for an article with the corresponding article number instead of acting according to the redirect set in the redirect manager.

So how do I prioritize the redirects over the interpretation of the article id's? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Aha! I found a way to disable the article interpretation from the Joomla routing. It's described on http://developernote.com/2012/05/how-to-remove-id-from-url-in-joomla-2-5.

Now this solution is commonly described online on several websites, most of which leave out the last bit. This one offers the full solution though. Anyways, thanks internet.